# Mysql query for parent child

Tags: mysql

```
  id   child    parent
   1    26       1
   2    25       1
   3    27       26
   4    28       45
```

i need get all child of `parent = 1` and also sub child of child
query return `1,26,25,27`

Comment: You need to provide some more details.  What have you tried, what doesnt work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

`select * from myTable where parent IN (select child from parent where parent=1) OR parent = 1`

Good Luck and hope this is what you want...

Comment: If it works, accept this answer. That's how Stack Overflow works.

Comment: @user787238 : Please accept the answer if it works... see Jong note